# C++ QPixmap fromImage segmentation fault

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qpixmap

I'm writing a program that requires frequent calls to the following slot function. This function worked normally in the beginning, but after a while, the segmentation fault appeared. `img` is delivered correctly and the problem happens in the `fromImage` function. How can I fix this?

```
void StitchWindow::showStitchImg(QImage img)
{
    img_label->resize(img.width(), img.height());
    QPixmap img_pix = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
    img_label->setPixmap(img_pix)
}
```

Comment: check your function input variable (img). It might be null in some cases and cause and segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

QImage use an implicit data sharing. you need to detach your data by calling

img.bits()

```
void StitchWindow::showStitchImg(QImage img)
{
    img.bits();
    img_label->resize(img.width(), img.height());
    QPixmap img_pix = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
    img_label->setPixmap(img_pix)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  There is something wrong with img. Bits (). I mistakenly thought that as long as the height and width of img are displayed, it is correct.